# sql server 2000: getting top N rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm running a simple query that gets the top 5000 rows of some table:

```
  SELECT TOP 5000 
         accountid, account, accountmanagerid, mainphone, alternatephone, fax, email, webaddress, createuser, modifyuser, createdate, modifydate, addressid, shippingid 
    FROM sysdba.account 
   WHERE 1 = 1 
     AND 1 = 1 
ORDER BY accountid asc
```

This perfectly worked on sql server 2008, but unfortunately now I find myself trying to run this formerly working script against SQL Server 2000. It seems to reject the top command.

What should I do to get back my 5000 rows on this version of the sql server?

Comment: According to [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), TOP is valid in 2000...

Comment: Keoki Zee is correct - `TOP` support started in SQL Server 2000.  You'll have to provide more detail than "it seems to reject the command".  IME, even with the compatibility level dialed back, I could still use later supported functionality.

Comment: From SQL Server 2005 it is possible to use an expression/variable in the TOP statement. In SQL Server 2000 it must be an integer value. Are you using a variable to specify the value 5000? If you are, you could use SET ROWCOUNT instead.

Comment: @gidireich : what exact error message do you see?

Comment: Out of curiosity, whats with the `WHERE 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1` ?

Answer (score 3):

TOP keyword isnt available in SQL Server 2000. However you can use rowcount to filter top records. You can modify the above query as below:

```
-- 1=1 is NOT needed unless you are appending this string as dynamic SQL

SET ROWCOUNT 50
SELECT 
         accountid, account, accountmanagerid, mainphone, alternatephone, fax, email, webaddress, createuser, modifyuser, createdate, modifydate, addressid, shippingid 
    FROM sysdba.account 
ORDER BY accountid asc
```

Comment: your solution works, however as I just check TOP is valid in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 2):

without TOP keywords also you can get solution for this question as follow-

```
select * from 
(
  select t_1.*,rownum c_1 from 
  (
  select accountid,account,accountmanagerid,mainphone,alternatephone,
       fax,email,webaddress,createuser, modifyuser,createdate,modifydate,addressid,hippingid
  FROM sysdba.account     
  WHERE 1 = 1-- whatever condition
    AND 1 = 1 -- condition 2 
  ORDER BY accountid asc 
  )t_1
)
where c_1 <5000
order by c_1
```